# Why did the defense barrier went down when Hyakkimaru mother stabbed herself?

Tags: dororo

In episode 12 of Hyakkimaru, when Hyakkimaru's mother stabbed herself why did the barrier went down? It is mentioned in previous episodes that Gate consisted of Demon aura, then why did it broke down?

Was Hyakkimaru's mother possessed with goddess? As when she stabbed herself, a green aura similar to the goddess idol went out of her and the demon gate broke down?